# How to use :not(.className) and pseudo selector after in React using Emotion.js

Tags: reactjs, emotion

how can you achieve somthing like this in emotion

```
.navBar__Link:not(.noborder)::after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 10px;
    height: 15px;
    width: 0;
    z-index:-1;
    
    background-color: var(--colorPrimary);
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
}
```

Comment: &:not(.noborder)::after ... In your components scope

Comment: @DennisVash this actually what I was looking for by component scoop u mean the component that would have navBar__Link as a className right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Composition](https://emotion.sh/docs/composition) and [String Styles](https://emotion.sh/docs/css-prop#string-styles) to achieve this. please refer to the documentation.

```
  css`
   &:not(.noborder)::after navBar__Link {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 10px;
     height: 15px;
     width: 0;
     z-index:-1;
    
     background-color: var(--colorPrimary);
     transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(0.25, 0.46, 0.45, 0.94);
   }
`;
```

Comment: thank you this is xlear answer , what about if I had something like this :
const navBarLink = app`some style` , 
so now navBar__Link is no longer a class how do rewrite ur answer